# Python expand './subfolder' into 'home/username/project/subfolder'

Tags: python

I have a function that takes in a path relative to the current working directory:

```py
get_full_path('./subfolder'):
```

It should expand the `./` notation into the full root path, returning:

```py
home/username/project/subfolder
```

Ideally I'd like a single `os` method that can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is in a single `os` method :

```
os.path.abspath("./some/relative/path")
```

Works with or without the `./` in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

This will return the path to the directory where the script is located.

```
import os

os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```